# Ajax post form serialise, post quotes '

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to let my code post HTML form values. It works but i cannot get it to post single quotes ' . I think this is due the usage of serialise. i so far changed to on post change the single quote to 2 single quotes, but it didnt work.

Javascript

```
    $( "#verstuur-bericht" ).click(function() {
    var nummeroftekensbericht=$.trim($("#message").val());
    if(nummeroftekensbericht.length>0)
    {
    $.post('http://192.168.178.24/server/submit.php', $('#bericht-verstuur-form')).serialize()
    $('#message').val('');
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()+40 }, 10);
  }, 1200);
  }
  else {
    Materialize.toast('Error: bericht is leeg!', 4000) // 4000 is the duration of the toast

  }

  });
```

Html

```
form id="bericht-verstuur-form" action="http://192.168.178.24/server/submit.php" method="post">
    <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="idu" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>" id="user_id"/>
        <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="nameu" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_full_name']; ?>" id="naam" placeholder="Enter name" />
      <input style="display:none;" type="number" name="user_level" value="3" id="user_level"/>



  <input placeholder="Typ hier!" style="width: calc(98% - 116px); color:#000; margin-left:15px;" name="message" id="message" type="text" class="validate input-chat-style">

  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right ">

    <a style="color:#444444; font-weight: bold; background-color:transparent; " id="verstuur-bericht">VERSTUUR</a>
  </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the single quotes?

Comment: @whipdancer you mean like to put the value between double quotes? or the $('#bericht-verstuur-form'))

Comment: more like `$(\'#bericht-verstuur-form\')`

Comment: @whipdancer Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: check out [this prior SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding    `.replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');` to serialize solved the problem!
      $.post('https://--', $('#bericht-verstuur-form').serialize().replace(/\'/g,'\\''))